# ASP.NET MVC 2 Telerik Editor not displaying formatted text

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, editor, telerik, telerik-mvc

I am having problems with the Telerik MVC editor control where it allows me to enter data, format it correctly (bold, etc.) and save this to a database. When I view the data in a browser it is displayed as I would expect (across all browsers).

When I try to edit the text again in the editor, it doesn't display the formatting correctly, but displays the HTML tags surrounding the text, that is, **working** opposed to the formatted text **working**.

When I save the data the second time to the database and view it again the data appears in this format: <strong>working description</strong>

This is the code I am using to display the text editor:

```
<% Html.Telerik().Editor()
    .Name("Description")
    .Value(Model.Description)
    .Render();
%>

// Code to the populate the model before saving to the database: There is no endcode or decode instruction here
article.Description = collection["Description"];
// Save changes.
```

To display the code in the browser I use this code:

```
<%=
    HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.Description)
%>
```

Hopefully this explanation makes sense and someone can help shed some light on this? I'm really confused as to how to make this work properly.

Comment: Just spotted a mistake, the first working which is in bold actually appears as <strong>working</strong>

IN the third paragraph where the text appears as <strong>working</string> the text is actually showing up as 
&lt;strong&gt;working description&lt;/strong&gt;


The auto formatting in stack overflow is too intelligent for me and I missed them when marking the code blocks!

Answer (score 2):

I am using [ASP.NET MVC 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC#Release_history) with Telrik control, and I used the below code and it's working fine.

**For Create Editor- In View Page**

```
 @{ Html.BeginForm(); }
            @Html.Telerik().EditorFor(model => model.Body).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:200px; width:500px;" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Body)

@{ Html.EndForm(); }
```

**in controller**

```
 public ViewResult Details(int id)
        {
            ArticleModels articlemodels = db.ArticleModels.Find(id);
            articlemodels.Body = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(articlemodels.Body);
            return View(articlemodels);
        }
```

**For Edit in View**

```
@Html.Telerik().EditorFor(model => model.Body).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:200px; width:500px;" })
```

Answer (score 0):

I made it working for me, hope it'll work for you.
In my view, I use this code:

```
<%: Html.Telerik().EditorFor(model => model.Description).Name("ContentEditor")%>
```

Then in the controller, I pass the value outside of the model (because the Model.Description property is always null, I don't know why yet), like that:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Detail(MyModel myModel, string contentEditor)
{
    myModel.Description = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(contentEditor);
    // Do stuff & save to DB
}
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for getting back to me, I tried this but am still getting the same problem unfortunately.
I think it is time to try another editor than the telerik version which is a pity

Comment: If you can switch to another editor, do it. The Telerik MVC components are not ready yet, it's like they are in some kind of public beta. If you try something just outside of the examples provided on their website, you have a 50% chance that you'll find a bug.